# tkinter - mistake in the layout

Tags: python, canvas, layout, tkinter, label

In the code below, I want the `label` on line 34 to go to the top of my canvas, as the `label` on line 59 does. But it goes to the bottom of my canvas instead, even though I'm using the same code in both places.

Here is my code (with code that causes problems marked with `#`):

```
from tkinter import*
from random import*

score = 0

Fenetre = Tk()

def Clavier(event):
    global coords
    global score
    global label

    touche = event.keysym

    if touche == "Up":
        coords = (coords[0], coords[1] - 10)
    elif touche == "Down":
        coords = (coords[0], coords[1] + 10)
    elif touche == "Right":
        coords = (coords[0] + 10, coords[1])
    elif touche == "Left":
        coords = (coords[0] -10, coords[1])

    canvas.coords(eater, coords[0], coords[1], coords[0]+20, coords[1]+20)

    while canvas.bbox(eater) == canvas.bbox(food):
        canvas.delete(food)
        label.destroy()
        global food
        up_score = score
        up_score = up_score + 1
        score = up_score
        label = Label(Fenetre, text = up_score) # line 34
        label.pack()
        X=choice(liste)
        Y=choice(liste)
        food = canvas.create_rectangle(X,Y,X+20,Y+20,fill="grey")

#fond = PhotoImage(file="Moi.gif")

canvas = Canvas(Fenetre, width=189, height=189)
#canvas.create_image(0,0,image=fond,anchor = NW)

coords = (0, 0)

liste_couleur = ["green","white","red","blue","yellow","violet","orange"]
couleur = choice(liste_couleur)
eater = canvas.create_oval(0,0,20,20,fill=couleur)

canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<Key>", Clavier)

liste = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180]
X = choice(liste)
Y = choice(liste)
food = canvas.create_rectangle(X,Y,X+20,Y+20,fill="grey")

label = Label(Fenetre, text = score) # line 59

label.pack()
canvas.pack()
Fenetre.mainloop()
```

If it matters, I'm using Python 3.2.

Comment: Why are you destroying a Label only to recreate it and try to pack it back into the same place? It would be a lot easier to just change the existing Label's text.

Comment: I destroy a label and recreate an other one because of the loop `while`. If i delete one of my Labels it cause errors like it `NameError: name 'up_score' is not defined` or `NameError: global name 'label' is not defined` because of the `def` . It also can come of me because I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: I don't understand that explanation at all. Why does the `while` loop mean you can't just change the existing label's text? And how does changing the existing label's text imply anything about deleting labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the new label doesn't go to the same place as the original label is… well, that's the way [the `pack` geometry manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) works: Where something goes depends on what else already exists at the time you `pack` it. The original label gets packed into an empty space, and then other stuff gets packed after it, so it ends up on top. The new label gets packed into a space that already has that other stuff, so it ends up on the bottom.

You *could* work around this by just passing the [`side=BOTTOM`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack-method) argument.

Or you could use a `grid` layout instead of a `pack` layout to make sure everything ends up exactly where you want it.

However, I think what you *really* want here is a lot simpler: instead of repeatedly destroying labels and creating new ones and hoping you can fit them in the same place, just keep the label and change its text.

In other words, instead of this:

```
    label.destroy()
    # other code
    label = Label(Fenetre, text = up_score) # line 34
    label.pack()
```

… just do this:

```
    # other code
    label.config(text=up_score)
```

Or, maybe even better, assign a `StringVar` to the `Label`, and just call `set` on that `StringVar` (as demonstrated in the next-to-last pattern in the [`Label`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) docs in the Tkinter book).